# Limit checkboxes but only those newly checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a bit of jquery that lets me limit the number of checkboxes a user can check on a page:

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 3");
    }
});
```

But, the user is limited to 'x' number once per day.  So they come to the form, submit their limit (3 checked).  They come back next day, I have the 3 checked that were from yesterday but set to disabled:

```
 checked="checked" disabled="disabled" disabled/>
```

Is there a way to modify my if statement to say "input[type=checkbox]:checked" but not if disabled or not if class="disabled" so these don't count against the daily limit?

Comment: Where are you storing the previously-checked check-boxes?

Comment: Are you checking this server side?  Those values can be easily changed in a user's browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [**`not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method for that like following.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').not(':disabled').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 3");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:enabled`

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:enabled:checked').length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("allowed only 3");
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there an advantage over ":enabled:checked" vs. ":checked').not(':disabled')"?

Comment: @Steve: simplicity? Readability?

Comment: Not really, they should both do the same thing